# How can I install PHP in Apache on OpenSUSE 13.2?

Tags: apache-http-server, php, opensuse

I have installed all of the following packages:

- apache2
- php5
- apache2-mod_php5

However, when opening a .php file in the web browser on my server, I am offered to download the file.

`apache2ctl -M` does not list mod_php as loaded.

Why does it not automatically load my PHP module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation process for apache2-mod_php5 seems to be broken. It adds the module with an incorrect name to the Apache config.

Open the file `/etc/sysconfig/apache2` and find the line starting with `APACHE_MODULES=`. At the end of this line the PHP module is added as `apache2-mod_php5`. This is an incorrect name, change this to `mod_php5` and restart Apache with `service restart apache2`.

The PHP module should now cload correctly.